# Gridview setEnabled not working for the first item

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a strange problem today. I am trying to implement a game where I have a gridview with some buttons. When any of the buttons are clicked, it get disabled (using `setEnabled(false)`). The problem is, only the first button is not getting disabled. Although the log output shows that `setEnabled(false)` is called for it.

Here is my code:

```
public class ButtonAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private GameScreen gameScreen;
    private Hangman hangman;
    private static final String[] buttonValues = 
        {
            "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G",
            "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N",
            "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U",
            "",  "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "" ,
        };
    private Button[] holder = new Button[getCount()];

    public ButtonAdapter(GameScreen gameScreen) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) gameScreen
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.gameScreen = gameScreen;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        View view = convertView;
        if(view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.game_button, null);

            final Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
            button.setText(buttonValues[position]);
            holder[position] = button;
            view.setTag(holder[position]);
        }
        else
            holder[position] = (Button) view.getTag();

        holder[position].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(buttonValues[position].length() != 0) {
                    Hangman.GameState gameState = hangman.updateCurrentWord(
                            buttonValues[position].charAt(0));
                    holder[position].setEnabled(false);

                    gameScreen.updateView(gameState);
                    Log.d("Button", position + ":" + holder[position].getText());
                }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return buttonValues.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return buttonValues[position];
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return holder[position].isEnabled();
    }
}
```

I've also tried `((Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button)).setOnClickListener(...);`, but no change.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more please. but try this -  `if(view == null)             {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.game_button, null);}`
and let button click listener be re-added. I didn't understand how you use holder[position] = button; as it's a view value which can be recycled by the system so not sure how you intend to use it.

Comment: Not related, but your keybord should read HIJK, not HIGK

Comment: @AshwiniBhangi, i've edited my code, now `OnClickListener` is added every time. But now the first item is not getting disabled when I click it.

Comment: @dberm22 Thank you, I haven't noticed it before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes these things happen becuase you are trying to access a view that has not been inflated yet. Try this:

```
    View view = convertView;

    if(view == null) 
    {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.game_button, null);
        vto = view.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {@Override public void onGlobalLayout() 
        {
            final Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
            button.setText(buttonValues[position]);
            holder[position] = button;
            view.setTag(holder[position]);

            ViewTreeObserver obs = view.getViewTreeObserver();
            obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }});
    ...
```

Or possibly put the `ViewTreeObserver` some place else. It all depends on which side of the `if statement` the code enters first.